# UInt32 decimal to UInt32 Hex conversion

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion

I have a `UInt32` variable, let's say its value is `4294964296`. I am trying to convert that number into its `UInt32` hex form, `0xfffff448` (not string), like so: `let valueU32: UInt32 = 0xfffff448`. Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is converting that `UInt32` number to `Int32`. Currently what I am trying to do is like so:

```
let valueU32: UInt32 = 0xfffff448
let value32: Int32 = Int32(bitPattern: valueU32)
```

But I have the `valueU32` in its decimal form and I am stumped here trying to convert `valueU32` from decimal form to an `UInt32` hex form. If anyone can help me figure out how to get that done, it would be helpful, or another way to go about converting `UInt32` to `Int32`.

Comment: What is wrong with `let valueU32: UInt32 = 4294964296;
let value32: Int32 = Int32(bitPattern: valueU32)` ?

Comment: Yea that works thank you - i was mixing some types while trying that statemtn. Also is there a way to convert let valueU32: UInt32 = 4294964296 into its hex form ?

Comment: Internally its all just bits.  There is no hex form or decimal form.  If you want to see what it is in hexadecimal then `print(String(valueU32, radix: 16))`.

Comment: Noted, you want to post it as the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the `UInt32` value represented by decimal `4294964296` to `Int32`, then just do this:

```
let valueU32: UInt32 = 4294964296
let value32 = Int32(bitPattern: valueU32)
```

Internally it's all just bits, so assigning `17`, `0x11`, and `0b10001` to a value all result in the same bits being set internally.

To see what a value looks like when represented in a particular base, use the `String` constructor that takes a `radix` (base):

```
print(String(valueU32, radix: 16))  // fffff448
```